# Jquery рассчитать расстояние от блока до края

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть такая структура. Центральный блок и по сторонам от него 2 блока с position:absolute. Нужно чтоб эти боковые блоки заполняли все место от центрального блока до края браузера. Я так понимаю, это можно сделать на jquery, рассчитав пространство между краем и центральным блоком и задать его боковым блокам. Плюс еще нужно чтоб при изменении ширины экрана, размер динамически подстраивался. Кто поможет сделать? спасибо

Update. Весь нюанс в том, что используется именно absolute. Поэтому нужно именно на jquery рассчитать это.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}

.element-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: violet;
}
.element-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="element-left"></div>
<div class="element-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `calc()` и вычислять размер динамически относительно ширины экрана и опять не нужен будет jQuery:

```
width: calc((100% - 300px) / 2);
```

правда есть недостаток - если ширина экрана меньше `300px + чуть-чуть` - тогда блоки будут залезать на центральный блок

тогда не нужно использовать никакой jQuery:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  height: 200vh;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.element-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc((100% - 200px) / 2);
  height: 100px;
  background: violet;
}

.element-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc((100% - 200px) / 2);
  height: 100px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="element-left"></div>
<div class="element-right"></div>
```

Может чуть-чуть передалать код и использовать только flex?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}

.element-left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background: violet;
}

.element-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="element-left"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="element-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: нее..незя ...читайте комментарии

Comment: @MaximLensky, а... я просто когда писал еще комментарии не появились :)

Comment: а я понять хочу - почему незя

Comment: @MaximLensky , можно сделать через calc - добавил еще пример

Comment: я плюсики тыкаю ...:))

Comment: В использовании `vw` есть один минус )  Попробуйте развернуть ваш пример на весь экран и задать для body `height: 200vh`

Comment: @zhurof, конечно, скрол мешает, но... если вы сделаете обёртку над 3 блоками `<div class = 'parent'>` с шириной `100%`, а в блоках в формуле будете использовать `100%` а не `100vw`, то все будет нормально - хотя проверил (изменил код выше) и без дополнительного div все будет работать!!!

Comment: @Zhihar , так я о том же. Лучше проценты (от экрана или от родителя). Так как ширина viewport включает в себя скроллбар

Comment: Вариант с calc хороший. Спасибо за идею.

Comment: @zhurof, да я перемудрил - я что-то подумал, что когда `position: absolute`, то это выводит элемент из под определения ширины и ничего не получится и поэтому сразу использовал не относительный, а абсолютный параметр

Answer (score 3):

Если ширина центрального блока нам известна, то ширина боковых блоков будет **50% экрана - половина_ширины_центрального_блока**. Для рассчёта этой величины не нужен `js`. Достаточно css-свойства `calc()` :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}

.element-left,
.element-right{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(50% - 150px);
  height: 100px;
  background: violet;
  
}
.element-left {  
  left: 0;  
}
.element-right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="element-left"></div>
<div class="element-right"></div>
```